# NULL elements in FOR XML Clause / Alternative to XSINIL

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have some legacy code similar to:

```
 ...
 '<field1>' +   
 case when field1 is null then '' else cast( field1 as varchar ) end +   
 '</field1>' +  
 ...
```

Which generates the following XML for empty elements:

```
 ....
 <field1></field1>
 ...
```

And I'm replacing the query with FOR XML:

```
 SELECT field1, 
 ...
 FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS
```

Now, this does not output an element for columns with NULL values.  I know about XSINIL:

```
 FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

But this generates a namespaced empty XML element, which is not compatible with the legacy code reading this output.

```
 ...
 <field1 xsi:nil="true" />
 ...
```

Any suggestions on generating the format below while still using the FOR XML Clause?

```
 ....
 <field1></field1>
 ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can double up on the columns that can have a null value with an empty string. The values will be concatenated and the empty string makes sure you will always have something that builds the node.

You need to use `for xml path` instead of `for xml raw`.

```sql
declare @T table
(
  Col1 int,
  Col2 int
)

insert into @T values(1, 2)
insert into @T values(1, null)
insert into @T values(null, 2)
insert into @T values(null, null)

select Col1,
       '' as Col1,
       Col2,
       '' as Col2
from @T
for xml path('row')
```

Result:

```xml
<row>
  <Col1>1</Col1>
  <Col2>2</Col2>
</row>
<row>
  <Col1>1</Col1>
  <Col2></Col2>
</row>
<row>
  <Col1></Col1>
  <Col2>2</Col2>
</row>
<row>
  <Col1></Col1>
  <Col2></Col2>
</row>
```

Answer (score 4):

One very simple solution would be: just don't specify the "XSINIL" after ELEMENTS!

```
 FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS
```

In that case, you'll just get no XML entry for any values that are NULL.

If you really want an empty XML tag, you need to use something like this:

```
SELECT
   ......
   ISNULL(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(100)), '') AS 'field1',
   ......
FROM dbo.YourTable
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS
```

thus turning the empty `field1` into an empty string and thus serializing it into the XML.

Comment: the "simple solution" is not compatible with the legacy stuff that reads the output. if barfs when the element is not present.               this ISNULL thing is nice, but a bit cumbersome.

Comment: that comment above sounded a bit cold. i'm grateful for the answer and I'm using this now! unless others come up.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid labor work of isnull by this

```
    declare @Var varchar(max)
set @Var=(select 
FirstName,
LastName,
Middldle_Name
From Customer 
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS xsinil , ROOT('Customer')
)
select CONVERT(xml,REPLACE(@Var,' xsi:nil="true"',''))
```